# Fire Subroutine when user leaves a date field ContentControl Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

Edit: I've updated the post with more info.

I have a Content Control **inside a header** in Word in which I have a date time picker. I'm trying to fire the _ContentControlOnExit event when the user leaves the focus (blurs) of the picker.

Let's suppose I've manually created a Content Control and I've assigned it a Date Picker. I've also tagged it with the value `date`.

I want that each time the date is changed, I perform a subroutine that will insert a text value to another ContentControl tagged `tide-level`. I tried the code below with no success.

Please, note that the date ContentControl is inside a header in the Word Document.

[image]

```
  Private Sub ActiveDocment_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
        If (ContentControl.Type = wdContentControlDate) Then
            MsgBox "Let's do it! Write the tide levels"

            dateObj = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTag("tide-level")
            dateObj.Range.Text = "wwwoohooo Tide Levels!"

            Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

I remember reading somewhere that whenever you have content in the header, it seems things get problematic...

Any ideas?

P.S:
Currently using Word 365 - VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the name of the procedure in the question - `ActiveDocment_ContentControlOnExit` - it appears the event handler was not generated automatically by Word *and* that it is therefore not in the `ThisDocument` class module of the document that contains the content controls. The name of the event handler (generated by the VBA editor) is usually `Document_ContentControlOnExit`.

The content control event handlers must be in `ThisDocument`. Theoretically, they could be typed manually, but Word doesn't always recognize manually typed event handlers. So it's better to use the VBA Editor's automatic "stub" generation to get the structures:

1. Open the ThisDocument module for the document that contains the content control.
2. In the code page window, at the top left, select "Document" from the drop-down.
3. from the top-right select the event to be inserted.

At this point, the VBA editor will create the "stub" for you - all that's needed is the code to be executed.

Note about the content control being in the header: This event does fire as long as focus when exiting remains in the header. If, however, the user double-clicks in the document body in order to exit the header the event doesn't fire. (At least, not in my tests.) If this is a problem you may want to put this field in the body of the document with a second, linked content control in the header to reflect the selection. Doing this is a bit complex (requires a Custom XML Part in the document to manage the linked information), but the version of Word you're using should have a tool for setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

the macro name should be:

```
Docment_ContentControlOnExit
```

NOT:

```
ActiveDocment_ContentControlOnExit
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that in the past, and that didn't seem to fire when the control is in the header portion of the document

Comment: It does, but not if you close the header to exit the content control.